# I'm getting error "Class 'Predis\Client' not found" in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, redis, composer-php, laravel-5

I want to using Redis in laravel 5.2 however, I'm getting error such a Class 'Predis\Client' not found, How I can solve it.

Comment: Your explanation is not sufficient to solve the problem. Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @smartrahat for me this explanation was sufficient - question was precise and clear.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

1. First download the [REDIS](http://redis.io/download) to your system (if you haven't already installed it).
2. Go to the folder where you have downloaded the redis and run this command:

   ```
   cd your-redis-folder-name
   make
   ```
3. Go to your project directory and install composer:

   `composer require predis/predis`
4. Go to your .env file and add Queue driver:

   ```
   QUEUE_DRIVER=redis
   ```
5. use `Mail::queue()` to send mail via queue. See [Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail).
6. And in your terminal run:

   ```
   php artisan queue:listen
   ```

   to send.

Comment: what does ```cd your-redis-folder-name make``` mean? when I do this it throws:: The term 'make' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet. and when I write ```cd my-redis-extracted-folders make``` it errors A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'make'.

Answer (score 44):

Write in console in project folder:

```
composer require predis/predis
```

And thats all.

Answer (score 7):

You need to add `predis/predis` into `composer.json` for your project. Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/redis#introduction

Answer (score 5):

Btw, if you are using laravel workers, with ubuntu supervisor and this error will not dissappear even after you did

```
composer require predis/predis
```

Then remember kids, that supervisor caches all your php code, once you boot it. So installing predis after you booted supervisor workers (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#supervisor-configuration), will not make a difference, until you do

```
sudo supervisorctl stop laravel-worker:*
```

and then start it again

```
sudo supervisorctl start laravel-worker:*
```

I've been stuck on this for an hour or two, on 3 projects in the last year.

Answer (score 4):

we have add composer.json file "predis/predis": "~1.0" help working fine.

Answer (score 2):

you can also try to run Redis as a [local server](https://github.com/eymeen/redis), download this and run the `run Redis server` file

if you still get it use `composer require predis/predis`

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem just including the `use Predis;`  above class file in app folder.

If you installed predis via  composer require predis/predis already.

Answer (score 0):

Running `composer dump` after installing predis/predis package might be necessary

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to just look at the path and filename Examples that exist Most of the path name or autoload file name are not spelled correctly

1-go to https://github.com/predis/predis/tags

2-create folder in host by name redis

3-download predis and upload to your website dir (www) in redis

4- create index.php out of the predis folder(redis)

5- past this code for test in index.php

```
require 'redis/Autoload.php';
Predis\Autoloader::register();
$client = new Predis\Client();
$client->set('foo', 'bar');
$value = $client->get('foo');
echo $value;
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I updated the .env file through Envoyer to use redis as the session and cache drivers prior to deploying the composer lock file. This was causing composer install to fail on deployment.

Resolved by changing the session and cache drivers back to file, then deploying the updated composer lock file and running composer install, then updated the session and cache drivers back in the .env file back to redis and redeployed again.