# Pagodabox - Class 'Predis\Client' not found in /data/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Database.php:62

Tags: php, laravel

I have a website hosted on pagodabox and I keep getting the following error.

> Class 'Predis\Client' not found in /data/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Database.php:62I have already checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865064/i-m-getting-error-class-predis-client-not-found-in-laravel-5-2), but my problem is specifically related to the pagodabox host. I have contacted support, no response from them and I am thinking i;m not gtoing to hear back from theb since this has tro do with the app itself.

I tried updating and recompiling the build on the server to run the updated composer.json file with predis/predis, but this didn't do anything. i followed the instructions in the answer above, but it's not working on my server. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

1. Remove `composer.lock`
2. Remove `vendor` folder
3. Run `composer install`

Hope this helps

Comment: It sure did! Thanks!