# Class 'Predis\Client' not found loop

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I tried all the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865064/i-m-getting-error-class-predis-client-not-found-in-laravel-5-2), but no luck.

The weird part is that if I simply run the command `composer update` I get this:

```
forge@development:~/default$ composer update
Cannot create cache directory /home/forge/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /home/forge/.composer/cache/files/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
> php artisan clear-compiled
The compiled class file has been removed.
> php artisan ide-helper:generate


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Class 'Predis\Client' not found
```

Running just `php artisan ide-helper:generate` gives me

```
  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Class 'Predis\Client' not found
```

Deleting the entire `vendor` directory then running `composer install` gives me [this output](https://gist.github.com/abbood/7bad7c725684a5a59ed160a50db5a33b).

This is my [composer.lock](https://gist.github.com/abbood/6a62f5440dbb2642c70599fd5d54e78c) and my composer.json files.

Running the command `composer require predis/predis` also returns the same error:

```
> php artisan clear-compiled
The compiled class file has been removed.
> php artisan ide-helper:generate


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Class 'Predis\Client' not found
```

Do you have any ideas?

## Update

This is a work around, but not a root solution. Running:

```
 composer update --no-scripts
```

that will skip the

```
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
       ..
    ],
    "pre-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan ide-helper:generate",
        "php artisan ide-helper:models -N",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
```

part, which is good enough for now. This indeed seems like a bug with laravel-ide-helper, reporting bug soon.

Comment: can you show us your composer require code

Answer (score 1):

From the [`laravel-ide-helper`](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) readme:

> When you receive a FatalException about a class that is not found, check your config (for example .... remove Redis ServiceProvider when you don't use it)

So, remove `RedisServiceProvider` and `Redis` alias from `config/app.php` if you don't use Redis. Then clear config cache with `php artisan config:clear`.

Comment: Except that I _am_ using it! The point of all  this  is to migrate from beanstalk to redis!

Comment: I already added the same question as a comment to the existing issue here: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper/issues/172

Comment: @abbood but it's not related to the original issue. You should really start a new issue.

Comment: Ok will do and post the link.. @gym now :p

Comment: for now a quick work around is to simply run `composer update --no-scripts`.. that will skip the ```-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan ide-helper:generate",
            "php artisan ide-helper:models -N",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        ``` part

Comment: After delete redis of my app.php config file, I get this error: Class redis does not exist