# full namespace vs registered class alias

Tags: laravel

my problem is in tinker i tried to set value with `\Redis::set("name","john")`
in redis and got this error:

```
PHP Error:  Non-static method Redis::set() cannot be called statically in Psy Shell code on line 1
```

but when using for example `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::set("name","john")` it works and everything is ok.

with this registeration in `app.php` by default:

```
'aliases' => [
    'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
],
```

so
`\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::set("name","MOHSEN") = \Redis::set("name","john")`

what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel uses the predis extension, and php also installs and uses the phpredis extension. Since both of the above redis extensions use Redis as the namespace, namespace conflicts are caused. Therefore in your Laravel project, you used predis before, but now switch to phpredis. Then the static method in the previous code will report an error.

Solutions to solve the cause
method one: In Laravel, since predis is an extension made based on PHP, it can be added through composer to facilitate integration with Laravel. Therefore, you can avoid conflicts by annotating the extension of phpredis in php.ini.

```
;extension = redis.so
```

Disadvantages:
predis maintenance has been cancelled, Laravel has started from version 6, it is recommended to use phpredis.

Method 2: In the code, clearly indicate Redis

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;
```

Method 3: change aliases Also stable
in config\app.php

```
'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class
```

Replace with

```
'The desired name' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class
```

And finally, use the desired name;

The second method is a more appropriate option. You can replace it with a small amount of code.

Comment: so what is the solution?

Comment: PHP Error:  Class 'Predis/Client' not found in /var/www/html/laravel8/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connectors/PredisConnector.php on line 26
(method 3)

Comment: Check out this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865064/im-getting-error-class-predis-client-not-found-in-laravel-5-2